# running bsub command from perl script

Tags: perl, shell, lsf

I am trying to run a bsub command from a perl script in the following way:

```
system ("bsub -select "testid::1" -q normal");
```

but I think perl is getting confused because of the double quotes in `"testid::1"`. What is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: Change either the outer or inner quotes to single quotes: `'`

Comment: Hi @HunterMcMillen, Thanks for your reply. But I have a more complicated problem. My bsub command also has a single quote so it looks like:system ('bsub 'select[type==LINUX64&&clearcase]'-select "testid::1" -q normal');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape the inner quotes:

```
system ("bsub -select \"testid::1\" -q normal");
```

or replace the outer quotes with single quotes, or in fact any character at all, thanks to the [`qq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qq.html) generalized quote operator in Perl which exists precisely for this sort of scenario;

```
system (qq{bsub -select "testid::1" -q normal});
```

There is a companion generalized single quote operator [`q`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/q.html).

Comment: Yes, to using `qq`. But a big no to using relatively obscure delimiters like "^". What's wrong with `qq( ... )`?

Comment: That's fine and probably an improvement.  I was just demonstrating that you can really use any character at all.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than fitting the entire command in a single quoted string (although using the generalized quoting operators makes that fairly simply), you can use the multi-argument version of `system` to avoid needing to quote the entire command line.

```
system 'bsub', 'select[type==LINUX64&&clearcase]', '-select', 'testid::1', '-q' 'normal';
```

Comment: +1 as this also avoids pesky security problems as you avoid invoking a shell altogether.